# WPF BInding & Reflection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, rowdetails

I'm generating a DataGrid by using On AutoGeneratingColumns. The whole process is highly dynamic and based on metadata. Each record (row) that is diplayed in the DataGrid is technically a class, which is derived from a base class.

The base class contains a property which returns a list of the displayed columns per record.

something like

```
GetType().GetProperties().Where(...).ToList();
```

Now, I want to edit the value of each property of the record by using the RowDetails.

The RowDetails are displayed in a ListBox which binds it's ItemsSource to former mentioned property of the bas class.

Displaying everything works fine, but when I'am changing a value, nothings ever reaches the set-method.

The TextBox would look like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the setter is never hit then the data doesn't transfer to the viewmodel. Since this is  a textbox which'll have two way binding on it's text you're unlikely to be over writing your binding. You get the correct value in the textbox initially?  No binding failures in your output window?

Comment: @Andy:
I just found out, the viewmodel is null. But the initial values are correct. How can that be? Is there a possibility to re-set the viewmodel?

Comment: @Daniele Sartori: yes, I do.

Comment: RowDetails doesn't inherit the datacontext of the DataGrid. Check which DataContext you have in your RowDetails

Comment: If you don't implement inotifypropertychanged on the viewmodel and raise property changed on the property you have bound as it changes then that could display ok initially. Say you later change it somehow to null or whatever. That would not then show in the view. Or you're just looking at the wrong thing now.

Comment: I found the issue, my Binding was set to the wrong object. So, @Andy, you were absolutely correct. Problem solved. Thanks for your help, guys.